# Ignore error in bash script for sun grid engine / grid scheduler

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, sungridengine

I've found that any bash error in my SGE job will cause the entire job to stop, and put into an error state. I understand the significance of that, but there are circumstances where bad programming can lead to bash errors and I'd like to ignore those errors and continue running the rest of the SGE job.

Is it possible to have qsub/SGE not put the job into an error state when a bash error occurs?

Answer (score 0):

If you chain multiple scripts then it's easy.

`bash script_a.sh || true && bash script_b.sh || true`